# ASP.NET Website Madam routes css requests to wrong authentication module

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP .NET website which uses Forms authentication to secure certain parts of the site. The site has a module that uses custom Basic authentication. 
I use Madam https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx to route specified request.url to Basic Authentication handler.
My Web.config specifies which requests go to basic authentication.

```
<madam>
<formsAuthenticationDisposition>
      <discriminators all="true">
        <discriminator
           inputExpression="Request.Url"
           pattern="/RouteMeToBasicAuthentication"
           type="Madam.RegexDiscriminator" />
      </discriminators>
    </formsAuthenticationDisposition>
  </madam>
```

As a result requests to ‘/RouteMeToBasicAuthentication’ are routed correctly to basic authentication.
I can log into my application using forms authentication.
The problem is that all .js and .css requests are routed to my Basic authentication module. These requested are originated from Forms authenticated .aspx pages. As a result all .js and .css requests are rejected as unauthorized

```
1.  Request URL: http://myApplication/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js
2.  Request Method: GET
3.  Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

I do not want .js and .css requests forwarded to the basic authentication module. How to do this? Why Madam routes these requests to the Basic Authentication?

Without Madam IIS assumes that resources such as .js, .jpg, etc, are all static resources, and thus doesn't need to pass them through the ASP.NET engine. I do not also want .js request to go to the ASP.NET engine since it has negative effect on the application performance.

A dirty workaround would be that I white list my css and js folders in the custom basic authentication module. I do not want to do that. I would like to have the problem fixed in the right place. How to do that?

Comment: We decided not to use Madam, since it rather old and complicated.So for me this question is not valid anymore.